# Deriving Ampere's law from Biot-Savart equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, magnetostatics

As an exercise, I've been trying to derive Ampere's law from the Biot-Savart equation (in the static case). So basically I'm trying to prove:

\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \mu_0\vec{J}(\vec{r})
\end{equation}

starting from:

\begin{equation}
\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')\times(\vec{r} - \vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|^3} d^3r'
\end{equation}

For the moment, here's what I've been able to do. First, I've expressed the magnetic field as the curl of a vector potentiel:

\begin{equation}
\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \nabla \times \underbrace{\left[ \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right]}_{=\vec{A}(\vec{r})}
\end{equation}

Then I have applied a curl on both side of the equation:

\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \nabla \times \nabla \times \underbrace{\left[ \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right]}_{=\vec{A}(\vec{r})}
\end{equation}

From there I used the vectorial identity:

\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec{A}(\vec{r}) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{A}) - \nabla^2\vec{A}
\end{equation}

So my equation becomes:

\begin{align}
\nabla \times \vec{B}(\vec{r}) &= \nabla \left[ \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right) \right] - \nabla^2\left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right) \\
&= \nabla \left[ \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right) \right] -  \left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \nabla^2\frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right) \\
&= \nabla \left[ \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right) \right] +  \left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \vec{J}(\vec{r}') 4 \pi \delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}') d^3r' \right) \\
&= \nabla \left[ \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right) \right] +  \mu_0 \vec{J}(\vec{r})
\end{align}

,where I used the identity:

\begin{equation}
- \nabla^2 \left(\frac{1}{\left|\vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} \right) = 4\pi\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}')
\end{equation}

So the second integral gives me exactly the wanted expression. The problem then only consist of proving that the first integral is equal to zero:

\begin{equation}
\nabla \left[ \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} d^3r' \right) \right] = 0
\end{equation}

I have already tried a couple things but I am unable to make this integral vanish. I'm clearly missing an obvious mistake, but I haven't been able to locate it. This is similar to other questions that have been asked before, but I have a specific question about a step in the derivation which is not answered elsewhere.

Comment: $\nabla\cdot\vec A$ *is* zero, since you've chosen the Coulomb gauge for the vector potential. (Usually you would do this the other way- fix the gauge and then show that that leads to the form you have for $\vec A$.) Asking how to do an integral is definitely not on topic for this site, though. See the [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: Also, now that I'm looking at this, you don't appear to have actually used the Biot-Savart law anywhere in your derivation?

Comment: @Chris:  The same integral arises if you try to prove Ampere's law from Biot-Savart without introducing a potential.  See, e.g., §5.3.2 of Griffiths.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Proof of Ampère's law from the Biot-Savart law for tridimensional current distributions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234360/)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  The integral itself does not vanish, but its divergence does.  Bringing the divergence inside the integral, we have
$$
\nabla_r \cdot \left( \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|}  d^3r' \right) = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \vec{J}(\vec{r}') \cdot \left[ - \frac{\vec{r} - \vec{r}'}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|^3} \right] d^3r',
$$
where $\nabla_r$ corresponds to the gradient with respect to $\vec{r}$.  But we also know that
$$
\nabla_{r'} \left( \frac{1}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|} \right) = \frac{\vec{r} - \vec{r}'}{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|^3},
$$
where $\nabla_{r'}$ is the gradient with respect to $\vec{r}'$.

Proceed from here.  You will need to make an additional assumption concerning $\vec{J}(\vec{r})$ to obtain Ampere's Law.